# Conditional styling in SolidJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, solid-js

I have a Component in SolidJS that looks something like this:

```js
const MyComponent: Component = (params) => {
  // ...
  const [votes, setVotes] = createSignal(new Set());
  const toggle = (val: string) => {
    if (votes().has(val)) {
      let _votes = votes();
      _votes.delete(val);
      setVotes(_votes);
    } else {
      let _votes = votes();
      _votes.add(val);
      setVotes(_votes);
    }
  }

  return <>
    <For each={someArray()}>{(opt, i) =>
      <button 
        style={{
          color: `${ votes().has(opt) ? "blue" : "black"}`
        }} 
        onClick={() => { toggle(opt) } }
      >
        {opt()}
      </button>
    }</For>
  </>
}
```

What I want to happen, is that the styling of the button will change, based on wheter it (`opt` in the for loop) is present in the `votes` set.

However, this code does not work. It doesn't update when the votes are updated.

The votes variable does update as expected.

When I give the votes set an initial value, the correct style is displayed (but it isn't updated afterwards).

Is there any solution to make this work?

Comment: It looks like you're mutating the same `Set` the entire time. You might want to create a new Set in your `toggle` function, something like `let _votes = new Set(votes());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a reactive `Set` primitive in [@solid-primitives/set](https://github.com/solidjs-community/solid-primitives/tree/main/packages/set#readme) that you can directly use as state without `createSignal`. This might simplify things for you.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, works as expected!

Answer (score 7):

What @Nick said seems to be correct, try changing your `toggle` method to:

```
  const toggle = (val: string) => {
    const _votes = votes();
    _votes.has(val) ? _votes.delete(val) : _votes.add(val);
    setVotes(new Set(_votes));
  }
```

[Playground](https://playground.solidjs.com/?version=1.4.1#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-cjWc6IGDuAXmYd+lj8fSS-Jkmt+id+6PkY3ViEonEVTHxN41pyJQKED4+havhEtGY9Hgr45HgTAAouif64AAQvgACSyrbIQhAqI0ACEzJgJIcxAA)

Comment: Great solution, works as intended now. @lexLohr's solution seems cleaner as it doesn't require the setVotes.

Answer (score 4):

The question has an accepted answer but actual question is how to track values stored in a set, not how to style an element. Scroll down to see how to style an element.

Solid does not track `Set`s out of the box because it relies on the Proxy API for tracking changes on an object. There are several alternatives but problem is mutating a set does not trigger an effect unless we replace it with a new set like `setVotes(new Set(votes().values()));` because sets are reference values. Since you are passing the same value in your question, signal is not updated.

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal } from "solid-js";

const App = () => {
  const [votes, setVotes] = createSignal(new Set());

  const castVote = () => {
    if (votes().has(4)) {
      votes().delete(4);
    } else {
      votes().add(4);
    }
    setVotes(new Set(votes().values()));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        style={{
          color: votes().has(4) ? "blue" : "red",
        }}
        onClick={castVote}
      >
        Toggle
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
render(App, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

Now, on updating an element's style.

Currently there are two ways to define an inline style on an element:

- Using an object with kebab-case keys.
- Using a plain string as we do with HTML elements.

You can use a ternary operation or other conditional expressions to create a value conditionally.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [cond, setCond] = createSignal(true);

  const toggle = () => setCond(c => !c);

  return (
    <div onclick={toggle}>
      <span>conditon: {cond() ? 'true' : 'false'}</span>
      {` `}
      <span
        style={{ 'background-color': cond() ? 'red' : 'blue', color: 'white' }}
      >
        Using Object
      </span>
      {` `}
      <span
        style={`background-color: ${cond() ? 'red' : 'blue'}; color: white;`}
      >
        Using String
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

render(App, document.querySelector('#app'));
```